# How to pass custom field value to shortcode?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I want to call custom field in `single.php` template to complete a short code and thus show a menu.

I places the below code but it is not working

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[custommenu menu=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘tabmenu’, true); ?>]?>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot to add quotes around the menu parameter.

```
<?php $post_meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tabmenu', true);
echo do_shortcode('[custommenu menu="'.$post_meta_value.'"]'); ?>
```

Comment: This works but he issue is that. I have two menus say MENU0 MENU1. But this code shows Menu0 on every post either I have MENU0 or MENU1 in tabmenu custom field

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. Hope this will work.

```
$post_meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tabmenu', true);
echo do_shortcode('[custommenu menu='.$post_meta_value.']');
```

Comment: its not working returning the same code on page